# How to plot a bar plot in realtime using matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, real-time

I've a continuous stream of data which is basically bins of a histogram.
I can plot a in real-time if use something like following:

```
import pylab as plt 
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, show
import numpy as np

plt.ion() 
X = np.linspace(0,4095,16)  
Y = np.linspace(0,10000,16)
f, axarr = plt.subplots(4, sharex=True)
graph_low,  = axarr[0].plot(X,Y,label='SomeLabel')
graph_low.set_ydata(Z)
```

But this only plots a line-plot.

The issue is I can't find something similar to set_ydata for a bar plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do the job for you?

```
ax = plt.bar(left, height)
ax.patches[i].set_height(x)
```

where `i` is the index for a particular bar and `x` is the desired height.